# How to read second line from a string in java

Tags: java, parsing, line

I have a string with multiple lines and I want to read a specific line and save it to an other string. That's my code

```
String text ="example text line\n
example text line\n
example text line\n
example text line\n
example text line\n
example text line\n
example text line\n";

String textline1="";
String textline2="";
```

on the above strings textline1 and textline2 I want to save the specific line.

Comment: I hope that's just a typo because you can't declare multiline strings like that.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many "lines" there are?  Will you only ever read the second line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can split on the new-line character:

//To split on the new line

```
String[] lines = s.split("\\n");
```

//To read 1st line

```
String line1 = lines[0];
System.out.println(line1);
```

//To read 2nd line

```
String line2 = lines[1];
System.out.println(line2);
```

Comment: i tested it to a new class and you are right. it's working...something  don't match with my code. thank you

Comment: If you just want the second line of the String, don't forget to use the limit parameter of the method split. `s.split("\\n", 2);`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s `Splitter` to turn `text` into an `Iterable<String>` (call it, say, `lines`). Then it's just a matter of getting your element via `Iterables.get(lines, 1)`;

Comment: To be fair, `Iterable` doesn't have a `get` method, so you'd have to copy it to a list first.  =/

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.io.LineNumberReader` may also be useful here, as it handles the various types of line endings that may be encountered.  From its [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html):

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Example code:

```
package com.dovetail.routing.components.camel.beans;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public final class SoTest {

    private String text = "example text line 1\nexample text line 2\nexample text line\nexample text line\nexample text line\nexample text line\nexample text line\n";

    String textline1 = "";
    String textline2 = "";

    public void testLineExtract() throws IOException {
        LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(text));
        String currentLine = null;
        String textLine1 = null;
        String textLine2 = null;
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (reader.getLineNumber() == 1) {
                textLine1 = currentLine;
            }
            if (reader.getLineNumber() == 2) {
                textLine2 = currentLine;
            }
        }
        assertThat(textLine1).isEqualTo("example text line 1");
        assertThat(textLine2).isEqualTo("example text line 2");
    }

}
```